# wordpress post filter using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a new     post type called `products` and i create a new taxonmy for this product  called `product_cat`.

```
register_taxonomy( 'product_cat', array( 'product' ), $args );
```

In the product_cat  i have added car ,ship,boat,bus etc.

Now i am listing  all the product using following code .

```
 args=array(
        'post_type'=>'product',
        'post_per_page'=>'10');

        $loop=new WP_Query($args);

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

        the_title();
        the_content();

        endwhile;
```

**I want to make a product filter now** .For this i added the  following   html

```
<label class="type-label">car<input type="checkbox" class="type-box" value="car"/></label>
<label class="type-label">bus<input type="checkbox" class="type-box" value="bus"/></label>
```

What i need is, when someone clicking the car then then car  products only    need to show .

I know the jquery code to fetch the  value of check box  .  i know how to `list car product`.

```
 $args=array(
            'post_type'=>'product',
            'post_per_page'=>'10',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'car',
                    ),),);
$loop=new WP_Query($args);
```

But please any one help to  show the corresponding result using ajax . That is when some one clicking the   car    check box then only product in car category need to show.

Please any one can help and give a simple example

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add an AJAX Action in wordpress, just like this:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

In your php function you can get parameters from the client, it could be the categody ID that you want to display.
Once got and checked all the parametes you need you can execute your query.

For the client impagination I suggest you to read this:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/

Hope this help you